# Drag and move multiple objects

Tags: android, touch, drag, move

After observing SDK samples, testing myself and searching a lot on stack overflow.Can't find any example with multiple object moved by touch. Any ideas ?

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: making a 2D ploting point for geometry. I want to place points on screen one by one (by touching screen) and draw segment between them.

Comment: seems to me like you need to implement  `ACTION_DOWN`, `ACTION_MOVE`and `ACTION_UP` and draw the objects on up and down. and draw the line on move. try looking at [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PmOtvJqDfqY&list=PL34F010EEF9D45FB8&index=74&feature=plpp_video)

Comment: Understand perfectly this tutorial but it consists on moving only one point.